# Search products and entries with pagination

Tags: entries, plugin-craftcommerce, search, pagination, products

Is there any way of searching both entries and products at the same time? Wanting a single search on the site which will return all entries and products containing the searched for phrase.

Looked at combining the results from `craft.entries.search()` and `craft.products.search()` but this stops us from using pagination which we would like to have. Anybody got a solution or suggestions?

Would prefer not to split into 2 search pages if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up creating a custom plugin to achieve this functionality. Also added some custom pagination logic. Set up a gist showing the variable and service files of the plugin as well as an example twig template to output the results.

https://gist.github.com/matt-adigital/e79b2fd2e14327b3f306a907f4e7e02e

All working well but it would be great if this was in core or just a little easier to implement. If we could leverage Crafts pagination for our own usage by passing in a dataset instead of being confined to the craft\elements\db\ElementQueryInterface object, then this would be a big help.

Another option could be to allow craft\elements\db\ElementQuery to accept multiple elementTypes or a null value, tried to submit with null but it is in fact required to be a string.

Hopefully anyone else who wants to use this functionality without going down the Algolia route will find this helpful.

Comment: Nice, just what I am looking for! But how add this as a plug-in? Or must this snippet added as an module? And is this snippet for craft 3 and commerce 2?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you would need to do 2 element query searches and combine the results on the front end.

Most developers tend to go for https://algolia.com when they want fast advanced search, including searching across elements.

Probably easiest to get started by searching for an Algolia plugin in the plugin store. I only know https://github.com/Rias500/craft-scout for Craft 3 at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your response Luke. Would be nice to have a built in function for this in the future if possible. Combining on the front end seems like it would cause pagination issues. Now that I know there is nothing available in core though I might try to throw together a plugin to achieve this. Trying to avoid adding any additional monthly costs such as Algolia for this client. Thanks again.